# Equal split of vector using two label vectors

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix consisting of three numerical vectors `data=[kids,mothers,fathers]` in which each vector contains the IDs of kids and their mothers and fathers. The IDs of kids are unique, but the IDs of fathers and mothers are non-unique (siblings and half-siblings exist). I wish to split the kids vector into two vectors of equal size with no family relationships across these vectors. I want these vectors to be as large as possible, but it may occur that some kids need be discarded to ensure equally sized vectors.

My current approach is to count the size of each 'family group' (=kids related through either parent) and then build equally sized groups using the size of each family.So far I've managed to count the number of kids that each mother or father has with:

```
mothersKids = arrayfun(@(x)nnz(mothers==x), mothers);
mothersKids = unique([mothers,mothersKids],'rows');
fathersKids = arrayfun(@(x)nnz(fathers==x), fathers);
fathersKids = unique([fathers,fathersKids],'rows');
```

This tells me how many kids are related to a single parent. Using the parent's ID I can figure out which kids are related and build groups based on that. However, I can't figure out how to combine the information of both parents to create the 'family groups'.

As a side-note: if a case occurs where kid A is related to kid B through one parent and kid B is related to kid C through one parent, but no relationship exists between kid A and kid C then for simplicity I will accept it if kid A and kid C are placed in the same family group.

EDIT::

Minimal example:

Input:

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6; 11,11,12,12,13,14; 21, 22, 23, 23, 24, 25]; % = [kids,mothers,fathers]
```

Output:

```
kidsInSameFamily = {[1,2],[3,4],[5],[6]};  
groupOne = [1,2,5];
groupTwo = [3,4,6];
```

Comment: minimal example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by building an adjacency matrix and using that to find subgraphs. Building groups of equal size seems to be a variation on the partition problem ([Partition Problems Brute Force Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34551720/partition-problems-brute-force-algorithm)), for which a MATLAB script that I may need to modify for my needs exists at https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/partition_problem/partition_problem.html

```
% Get kids associated through their mother.
storepairs =[];
for mom = unique(mothers)'
    idx = find(mothers==mom);
    if numel(idx) > 1
        pairs = nchoosek(idx,2);
        storepairs = [storepairs; pairs];
    end
end
% Get kids associated through their father. 
for dad = unique(fathers)'
    idx = find(fathers==dad);
    if numel(idx) > 1
        pairs = nchoosek(idx,2);
        storepairs = [storepairs; pairs];
    end
end

% Make pairs symmetric 
storepairs = [storepairs; fliplr(storepairs)];
% Add diagonal
storepairs = [storepairs; [1:size(data,1); 1:size(data,1)]'];
% Remove non-unique pairs
storepairs = unique(storepairs,'rows');
% Build adjacency matrix
A = sparse(storepairs(:,1),storepairs(:,2),1);
% Create a graph object
G = graph(A);
% Get sub-graphs within graph
SG = conncomp(G); 

% Kids in same family 
kidsInSameFamily={}; 
for ii = 1:max(SG)
    kidsInSameFamily{ii} = kids(SG==ii);
end
```